# Android Kotlin API Request | Access the list after the gson process

Tags: android, api, kotlin, gson, okhttp

Im trying to access my list in "mainactivity" -> StartActivity after the api request:

**"mainactivity" -> StartActivity:**

```
class StartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.startseite)

        fetchJson()



        ...



    }
    fun fetchJson() {
        println("Attempting to Fetch JSON")

        val url = "https://....."
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val statsVideoList: List<StatsVideo> = gson.fromJson(body, Array<StatsVideo>::class.java).toList()
                for (jetpack_featured_media_url in statsVideoList) {
                    println("The link is${jetpack_featured_media_url}")
                }

            }


            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed to execute request")
            }
        })
    }
}

class StatsVideo (val id: Int, val status: String , val title: Title, val jetpack_featured_media_url: String, val link: String)

class Title (val rendered: String)
```

and now i want to use the list in this Activity (StartActivity). E.g. load the `jetpack_featured_media_url` with picasso in an ImageView.

How do i access this String?

Now I want from **component1** the url / string **jetpack_featured_media_url** and load them with picasso.

My code:

```
Picasso.get().load(statsVideoList.component1().jetpack_featured_media_url).into(imageView)
```

but on app start i get this error
"

```
020-05-10 07:26:42.397 17384-17457/com.example.exampleE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.example, PID: 17384
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.checkMain(Utils.java:127)
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:679)
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:665)
        at vision.spectre.lernbox.StartActivity$fetchJson$1.onResponse(Startseite.kt:68)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:504)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

```
Method call should happen from the main thread.
```

But if I now want to make a button that starts a new activity and "transfer" a string with it

```
val buttonLatestVid = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
        buttonLatestVid.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, LatestVideoDetailActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("VideoLink", statsVideoLost.component1().jetpack_featured_media_url)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

is the staatsVideoList not accessable because it is not in the **onResponse**
but if i make my button in onResponse the Intent gives me this error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: public constructor Intent(packageContext!, Context!, cls:Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intentpublic constructor Intent(action: String!, uri: Uri!) defind in android.content.Intent
```

Comment: You can't take the response out of block. It is asynchronous, your function will just queue up the request and exit. It won't block the main thread till request is done, otherwise it will freeze your application. Can you provide the usecase of why you want to take response outside of block? To help you further. Btw why not use your list inside onResponse?

Comment: okay thanks. The question is may be a bit stupid, but I haven't found an answer to it. How do I get the val / var now? Probably something with statsVideoList. , but android studio only suggests functions for the list.
Maybe you can help me?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: thx for helping me

Comment: Hey can you help me again?
Added the problem to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequestCreator.into()` call should be happened from the main thread. Just change the thread before doing any UI changes.

**If you use coroutines:**

```kotlin
Picasso.get().load(statsVideoList.component1().jetpack_featured_media_url).also {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
        it.into(imageView)
    }
}
```

**If you don't:**

```kotlin
Picasso.get().load(statsVideoList.component1().jetpack_featured_media_url).also {
    runOnUiThread {
        it.into(imageView)
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: Coroutine way is way light and faster.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot

Comment: Can you help me again, I still have a problem. I added it back to the post. I'm sorry to bother you again.

Comment: @iGhost put `this@StartActivity` instead of this